# Sorting a template field in a pagedgridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to adding sorting functionality to a pagedgridview.

the pagedgridview contains information about an employee's clock in, clock out, etc.

The grid is populated by an sql database and I am able to sort every column by setting SortExpression but one.

The one column I can not sort is the "Duration" column where the row values are calculated in the .aspx page as shown in the code. Duration is calculated by subtracting clockin from clockout, so it is not necessary to store in my db.

How can I sort the grid when the column does not exist in the database?

```
                    <%-- Duration --%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# GetTimeSpanString(new TimeSpan(((DateTime)Eval("ClockoutDate")).Ticks - ((DateTime)Eval("ClockinDate")).Ticks)).Replace("0 hours", "0.1 hours") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: `Duration` is the header text not the field name. You need to write it as `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="ClockoutDate">`

Comment: Or, if you have access to the sql or stored procedure modify it to do the time math and return it as a field and problem solved. Otherwise you may need to read the data into something like a DataTable, add a column with the calculation, and use that as the datasource to the Grid so you have a field to sort on